# innerHtml works in console, but does not display result in html page

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I don't understand why innerHtml shows the good result in the console, but does not display anything in the html page :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="test" onclick="testClick();"></input>
  <p id="score2"></p>
  <script>
    var score = 0;

    function testClick() {
      score++;
      document.getElementById("score2").innerHtml = score; //does not display anything
      console.log("inner : " + document.getElementById("score2").innerHtml); //works
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Typo - `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Kinduser argh thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var score = 0;
function testClick(){
   score++;
   document.getElementById("score2").innerHTML = score;

}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="testClick();"></input>
<p id="score2"></p>
```

Here is the updated snippet for your code. your are doing a syntax mistake "innerHTML" is correct while "innerHtml" in incorrect

Comment: Please do not answer questions with typographical mistakes